# .double arrays to sse vectors and operations on them

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, sse, simd

This is my first contact with SSE. I'm trying to create two SSE vector based on a .double arrays and then multiply by each other and store the result back in one of the arrays. Here is an important part of the code:

```
.data
counts: .double 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0
twos: .double 2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0

.text

movupd counts, %xmm7
movupd twos, %xmm6

mulpd %xmm6, %xmm7

movupd %xmm7, counts
```

However, those instructions seem to affect only the first two elements of a vector.

This is the result: 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0
While it should be: 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0

Could someone point me what am I doing wrong?

It would of course be much easier if I could multiply a vector by a scalar but I haven't found a proper instruction to do so anywhere.

I'm checking those values by summing them up (what's my later task after I solve this one) with this code:

```
mov $0, %rsi
addsd counts(%rsi), %xmm0
mov $8, %rsi
addsd counts(%rsi), %xmm0
mov $16, %rsi
addsd counts(%rsi), %xmm0
mov $24, %rsi
addsd counts(%rsi), %xmm0
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `xmm` register can only hold two doubles, so you can only do two at a time. If you need to do all four in one go, use single floats or migrate to AVX.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the point. Regarding my second question - can you please tell me if there is a way to multiply a vector (xmm with two doubles) by a scalar?

Comment: @FilipJ, of course you can multiply a vector by a scalar.  You do something called a broadcast (e.g. with `_mm_set1_pd`) which puts the value of the scalar in each element of the register and then multiply.  See Paul R's answer.

Comment: Which is multiplying with a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go too far down this road let me strongly advise you to consider using intrinsics rather than raw assembly, otherwise you're likely to be spending a lot of unnecessary additional time and effort in coding and debugging. For example, to multiply two vectors as per your example:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>                    // SSE2 intrinsics

for (i = 0; i < N; i += 2)
{
    __m128d v0 = _mm_load_pd(&a[i]);      // v0 = { a[i], a[i+1] }
    __m128d v1 = _mm_load_pd(&b[i]);      // v1 = { b[i], b[i+1] }
    __m128d v = _mm_mul_pd(v0, v1);       // v  = { a[i]*b[i], a[i+1]*b[i+1] }
    _mm_store_pd(&c[i], v);               // store result at c[i], c[i+1]
}
```

and to multiply a vector by a scalar:

```
const __m128d vk = _mm_set1_pd(k);        // init scalar = { k, k }
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 2)
{
    __m128d v0 = _mm_load_pd(&a[i]);      // v0 = { a[i], a[i+1] }
    __m128d v = _mm_mul_pd(v0, vk);       // v  = { a[i]*k, a[i+1]*k }
    _mm_store_pd(&c[i], v);               // store result at c[i], c[i+1]
}
```